# Login screen in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, authentication, jframe

I am trying to create a JFrame login screen in Java. I have searched the internet and only found things on Netbeans which I do not want to use because I would like to make it entirely in code.

It would need to be that you could not see the usernames and passwords just by looking at the code.

I have created a JFrame:

```
JFrame launcher = new JFrame("Login");
```

And some widgets:

```
JTextField User = new JTextField("Username");
JPasswordField Pass = new JPasswordField("Password");
JButton Login = new JButton("Login");
```

But every time i do:

```
launcher.add(User)
launcher.add(Pass)
launcher.add(Login)
```

The Login button would coveer the entire window.

So here is the pseudo code of what I'm trying to do:

```
Login = create new button
Pass = create new Password Field
User = create new Text Field
Check = 0

add User at top of window
add Pass at middle of window
add Login at bottom of window

if Pass input == any password from list then {
     Check = Check + 1
}

if User input == any username from list then {
     Check = Check + 1
}

if Check == 2 {
     Change to new class
}else{
     Show on screen "INVALID" then restart
 }
```

Comment: Maybe [_this answer_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20286447/2587435) might give you some ideas. It uses a JDialog to login to a JFrame program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a layout manager set, so the JFrame's Default which is BorderLayout, is adding everything to the center, which means when you add pass, it covers over the user, then when you add the login button, it covers over the pass, so it looks like you only have a login button. In order to get what you want:

```
add User at top of window
add Pass at middle of window
add Login at bottom of window
```

An example of the code could be:

```
launcher.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
launcher.add(user, BorderLayout.NORTH);
launcher.add(pass, BorderLayout.CENTER);
launcher.add(login, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

If you want to make it check login when the button is clicked add an [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to login.

```
login.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         //Check login stuff here... 

         //with maybe something like this?
         String sLogin = login.getText();
         String sPass = pass.getText();
         //Then compare with some other string/data you already have saved somewhere...

     }
});
```

However if you want more exact layout, you can try searching up [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

If you want to read more about layouts in general go here: [LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: -1, this answer was already given an hour earlier. No need to clutter the forum with duplicate answers.

Answer (score 2):

> The Login button would coveer the entire window.

That is because the default layout manager for a JFrame is a BorderLayout and you are adding all the components to the "CENTER" (by default) and only the last component added is displayed.

So you need to choose a more appropriate layout manager.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GridBagLayout in netBeans . this layout is stable way for complex form and panel .

[tutorial for Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gbcustomizer-basic.html)

Comment: Netbeans is cheating. I want to make it in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code for login screen



class Login extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    Connection con=null;
    Statement st=null;
    ResultSet rs=null; 
    JLabel l1,l2;
    JButton b1,b2;
    JTextField t1;
    JPasswordField pf;
    Login(){    
        Toolkit tk=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Image img=tk.getImage("C:/Image.jpg");
    setIconImage(img);
        Icon icon1=new ImageIcon("C:/Image.jpg");
        JLabel i=new JLabel(icon1);
    JPanel p;
    p=(JPanel)getContentPane();
    p.add(i);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(243,67,226));
        setVisible(true);
        setLocation(225,50);
        //setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setSize(900,600); 
        setTitle("Login");
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        l1=new JLabel("UserName");   
        l2=new JLabel("Password");
        t1=new JTextField(10);
        AbstractAction action = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton){
            JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
            button.doClick();        
            } else if(e.getSource() instanceof JComponent){
                JComponent component = (JComponent) e.getSource();
                component.transferFocus();
            }
        }
        };

        t1.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "TransferFocus");
        t1.getActionMap().put("TransferFocus", action);

        pf=new JPasswordField(10);
        pf.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "TransferFocus");
        pf.getActionMap().put("TransferFocus", action);
        ImageIcon ic=new ImageIcon("C:/key.gif");
        b1=new JButton("Login",ic);
        b1.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "TransferFocus");
        b1.getActionMap().put("TransferFocus", action);
        ImageIcon ic1=new ImageIcon("C:/cancel.jpg");
        b2=new JButton("Exit",ic1);          
        b2.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "TransferFocus");
        b2.getActionMap().put("TransferFocus", action);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        JPanel p1=new JPanel();   
        JPanel p2=new JPanel();      
        JPanel p3=new JPanel();  
        JPanel p4=new JPanel();   
        p1.setBackground(new Color(243,67,226));
        p2.setBackground(new Color(243,67,226));
        p3.setBackground(new Color(243,67,226)); 
        p4.setBackground(new Color(243,67,226));
        p1.add(l1);
        p1.add(t1);
        p2.add(l2);
        p2.add(pf);
        p3.add(b1);
        p3.add(b2);
        p4.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        p4.add(p1);    
        p4.add(p2);
        p4.add(p3);
        add(p4);
        t1.requestFocus();
        //b1.requestFocus();
        //b1.requestFocusInWindow();
        validate();

    }  //eof cons.
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
         if(ae.getSource()==b1){
            try {
                try{
                    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                    String url=null,url1=null,userID=null,password=null;
                    String dbFileName=null;
                    String dbFileName1=null;
                    String sql=null;

                    dbFileName = "C:/db.accdb";

                    url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"+
                            "DBQ="+dbFileName+";";
                    con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);//,"system","manager"
                    st=con.createStatement();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                    dispose();
                }
                if(t1.getText().trim().length()==0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Enter User Name");
                    return;
                }
                if(pf.getText().trim().length()==0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Enter Password");
                    return;
                }



                ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select password from LOGIN1 where uname='"+t1.getText().trim()+"'"); 

                if(rs.next()){
                    if(rs.getString(1).equals(pf.getText())){
                        String smess="WEL-COME ";
                        String ss="Congratulations......";
                        int res=JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null,smess,ss,res);  
                        JFrame frm=new JFrame("Title");
                        className b=new className(frm);
                        frm.setSize(800,500);
                        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        frm.setResizable(false);
                        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                        dispose();
                        frm.show();
                    }else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Invalid Password");
                    }

                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Invalid User name");
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            }if(ae.getSource()==b2){
                dispose();
            }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Login();
    }

}
```

Comment: Either you use netbeans or you are a very messy programmer

Comment: I have created this Login frame in Netbeans only. And your second opinion about me, So my Name itself suggest that. Thank You!