# Form freezing issues after accessing dialogue box

Tags: java, swing

I'm in the process of creating a login mechanism for a game. If the user inputs an invalid username-password combination, a dialogue box appears telling them their error. But when I click "OK" in the dialogue box, all components in the previous form become inactive.

Here is my code from the event handler method:

```
//Event Handler
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    Scanner fileScan = null;
    Scanner passwordScan = null;


    String lineVar; 
    int lineCount=0;

    //Opens the "Create Account" form
    if (e.getSource()==CreateNew){      
        new CreateAccount();        
    }

    //user tries to login 
    else if(e.getSource()==submit){

        Inputuser = user.getText();
        InputPass = Pass.getText();

        try{
            fileScan = new Scanner(new File(Inputuser + ".txt"));
            filefound = true;
        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            JFrame FailureFrame = new JFrame("Something went wrong...");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(FailureFrame, "The username you have entered does not exist in our records. Please try again");
            filefound=false;
        }

        //If the file was found (username exists)
        if (filefound==true){

            //Loops while the username while has more lines of content          
            while(fileScan.hasNext()){
                lineVar = fileScan.next();

                //Each line is considered a token
                passwordScan = new Scanner(lineVar);
                passwordScan.useDelimiter("/n");

                while (passwordScan.hasNext()){
                    lineCount +=1;

                    if (lineCount == 2){

                        if (InputPass.equals( passwordScan.next() ) ){

                                JFrame successframe = new JFrame("Success!");
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(successframe, "Login Successful!");

                                frame.dispose();
                                new MainProfile();

                        }

                        //If the password they entered is wrong     
                        else{
                            JFrame notLogin = new JFrame ("Something went wrong...");           
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(notLogin, "You have entered invalid info. Please try again"); 

                            CompEnable();   

                        }

                    }


                }

            }


        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post a runnable example so we can test this out

Comment: Also, consider using a modal JDialog instead of two frame, like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20286447/2587435)

Comment: Should I post a zip file with my current work?

Comment: Use standard Java variable names if you want people to read your code. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. I have NEVER seen a tutorial or example from a text book that does that, so don't make up your own conventions. Follow the standards.

Comment: I was taught that. Anyway, ok though. Point noted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some hints below to guide you to solve the problem:

- Check the while loop, it seems to be blocking the [Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (a.k.a. EDT) and that's freezing your GUI. Also take a look to [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) trail for further details on how the EDT works and how to deal with it.
- You should avoid the use of multiple [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) and consider use modal [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) instead: [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html). Also take a look to this topic:  [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)
- You may want to try [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) to store user passwords and get rid of handling file's IO by using [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class. **Note:** ideally it should be done in a database but in this case you're doing this in a ".txt" file so I think properties would be more appropriate. Take a look to [this trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) and [How to use Java property files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318347/how-to-use-java-property-files) to start with properties.

**Off-topic:**

- Always try to follow [Java Code
  Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf).