# Java - JFrame keeps freezing after I type some Letters into a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paintcomponent, repaint

I have no Idea why my JFrame keeps freezeing after I type Letters into the JTextField "Username" and "Password" :/ Could anyone look thru my code and tell my why and fix it please ?

```
public class Main 
{       
    public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {    
        LoginWindow loginframe = new LoginWindow();
        loginframe.setVisible(true);
        loginframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        loginframe.initialize();    
        while(true)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            loginframe.Repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

FrameClass:

```
public class LoginWindow extends JFrame implements MouseListener, KeyListener, MouseMotionListener{

    public LoginWindow(){
        setSize(806, 629);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        background = new JLabel(ResourceLoader.Iconload("/main_01.jpg"));
        background.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);
        add(background);            
        background.setLayout(null);
        Username = new JTextField("", 20);
        Username.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        Username.setBounds(312, 433, 170, 40);
        Username.setFont(new Font("Impact", Font.BOLD, 25));
        Username.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        Username.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 5, 0, Color.BLACK));
        background.add(Username);           
        Password = new JPasswordField("", 20);
        Password.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        Password.setBounds(312, 489, 170, 40);
        Password.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        Password.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 5, 0, Color.BLACK));
        Password.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 25));
        background.add(Password);
    }

    public void initialize()
    {
        makestrat();    
        addKeyListener(this);
        requestFocus();
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);    
    }

    public void makestrat()
    {
        createBufferStrategy(2);
        strat = getBufferStrategy(); 
    }

    public void Repaint()
    {           
        //System.out.println(mouseX + " " + mouseY);
        Graphics g = strat.getDrawGraphics();
        paintComponents(g);
        Draw(g);
        g.dispose();            
        strat.show();
    }

    public void Update()
    {           
    }

    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        if(((mouseX >= 499) && (mouseX <=  669)) && ((mouseY >= 433)&&( mouseY <= 530))){
            g.drawImage(ResourceLoader.ImageLoad("/login_02.jpg"), 502, 459, null);
        }else{
            g.drawImage(ResourceLoader.ImageLoad("/login_01.jpg"), 502, 459, null);
        }
    }

    private class thehandler implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {   

        }           
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event)
    {
        mouseY = event.getY()-26;
        mouseX = event.getX()-3;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        Point point = new Point(a.getLocation());
        SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(point, e.getComponent());
        double mouseX = (int) point.getX();
        double mouseY = (int) point.getY(); 
        System.out.println("(ContainerPos) Mouse clicked! X: " + mouseX + " Y: " + mouseY);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {            
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {           
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you repaint the JFrame every 50ms?

Comment: You're blocking the `EDT` with `while(true)` making the gui irresponsive. don't block it. Don't use null layout

Comment: JFrame hasn't paintComponent, Swing hates  Thread.sleep(), everything there isn't about How is Custom Paintintg done in 21th. millenium

Comment: i tried it without Thread.sleep() it endeed in 100% processor use in one core :/ Is there another way to not make it refresh with a 0ms delay ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need the `while` loop with the `Thread.sleeap()`. It's screwing with your program.
2. What you're trying to achieve here, a call to repaint continuously, can easily be accomplished with a `javax.swing.Timer`
3. Don't explicitly call `paintComponent`. An *actual* call to the *real* `repaint()` method will do that for you. No need to create an imitation `Repaint()`
4. Use a `JPanel` for painting instead of trying to paint on a `JFrame`
5. I would initialize, *then* set visible
6. Your code doesn't even compilable, so I can try and make fixes for you.
7. Use Java naming convention: methods and variable start with lower case letters.
8. Here's an [example of a simple Login Window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20286447/2587435), using a modal `JDialog`
9. Learn how to use [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) instead of relying on `setBounds()`

---

**Point 2.** Your `main` should look like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            LoginWindow loginframe = new LoginWindow();
            loginframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            loginframe.initialize();
            loginframe.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

And in your constructor, have a `javax.swing.Timer` instead of your `while` loop

```
private Timer timer = null;
private DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel();  // see below for DrawPanel
public LoginWindow() {
    // add drawPanel somewhere
    ...
    timer = new Timer (50, new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            drawPanel.repaint();
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}
```

---

**Point 4.** Have an inner `JPanel` class that you do all your painting in, and add that component to the frame. You'll need to override the `paintComponent` method.

```
private DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graophics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Draw(g);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing is that you shouldn't use Swing (or AWT really) off of the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Fix with `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater` and `java.swing.Timer` (**not** `java.util`!). Diagnose with `jstack`(and `jps`) or the relevant key sequence in the terminal window (um, ctrl-break in Windows, ctrl-3 in Linux).

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand 90% of what you wrote, could you try to explain it in easier words and with examples please :) ?