# JFrame lock Log In Form in front of Main Form

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm writing an app and I want to set my Log In Form to the top of Main Form and always on top of the Main Form. I mean lock it in front of Main Form until the Log In Form closed, so User can access Main Form after the Log In Form is Closed.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20286447/2587435) for a simple login mechanism using a model `JDialog`

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  And I agree with the only answer so far offered, this needs a modal dialog, or easier, a `JOptionPane` (which is a modal dialog with some convenience methods).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can user `JDialog` instead of a `JFrame` for making a modal frame. Following two links can help you in getting started.

- [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html)
- [The New Modality API in Java SE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140695.html)

Comment: Can JDialog create an Log In from like JFrame?
Can you give me an example to create a JDialog to be like a JFrame?

Comment: @KaJasB: a JDialog can hold the exact same components as a JFrame, but it can also act as a modal dialog, just like what you need. Read the [API for the JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) to learn how to construct it so its modal. Do a little experimenting on your own with this, you won't regret this. 1+ to Jabir.

Comment: +1 - though I'd probably use the more specialized `JOptionPane` for this use-case..

Answer (score 0):

This follows the general idea outlined by @Jabir, but uses a [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) (which uses a modal dialog as the display component) because it has a number of convenience methods that do the heavy lifting we would otherwise need to implement in a plain modal dialog.

A dialog on the other hand, is **more versatile** that an option pane.  As soon as we start thinking *"That's great, but I'd like to alter it to.."* that is when to use a `JDialog` directly.  An option pane is harder to change beyond the (many) options offered by the existing API.

See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details of using option panes.

[image: Login Form]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class LoginForm {

    private JPanel loginForm = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
    private JTextField userID = new JTextField(12);
    private JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField(8);

    LoginForm() {
        initializeLoginForm();
    }

    /** 
     * Displays the log-in form inside a confirmation option pane. 
     * The result (OK/Cancel) of the option pane is returned for inspection.
     */
    public final int displayLoginForm(Component parent) {
        return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                parent, 
                loginForm, 
                "Log In", 
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }

    private final void initializeLoginForm() {
        JPanel labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,5,5));
        loginForm.add(labels, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        JPanel fields = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,5,5));
        loginForm.add(fields);

        labels.add(new JLabel("User ID:", SwingConstants.TRAILING));
        labels.add(new JLabel("Password:", SwingConstants.TRAILING));

        JPanel userIdConstrain = new JPanel(
                new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        userIdConstrain.add(userID);
        fields.add(userIdConstrain);

        JPanel passwordConstrain = new JPanel(
                new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        passwordConstrain.add(password);
        fields.add(passwordConstrain);
    }

    public final String getUserID() {
        return userID.getText();
    }

    public final char[] getPasword() {
        return password.getPassword();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JLabel l = new JLabel("<html>"
                        + "<body style='width: 300px; height: 175px;>",
                        SwingConstants.CENTER);
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Secure Application");
                f.add(l);
                // Ensures JVM closes after frame(s) closed and
                // all non-daemon threads are finished
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556 for demo.
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                // ensures the frame is the minimum size it needs to be
                // in order display the components within it
                f.pack();
                // ensures the minimum size is enforced.
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());
                f.setVisible(true);

                LoginForm lif = new LoginForm();
                int result = lif.displayLoginForm(f);
                // do the approrpaite action for this result
                if (result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                    l.setText("Welcome " + lif.getUserID());
                } else {
                    l.setText("This application requires authentication!");
                }
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```